# Detect user actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to build lock app if the user didn't do any thing with the app after 2 min.

there is anything that can inform me every time the user made touch,scroll,pinch... on every screen in the app?

Comment: you can use gesture recognizers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of UIApplication. Modify the following line in the main.m file:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"CustomApplication", nil);
```

Where CustomApplication is your UIApplication subclass name.

Now you can override the `-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event`method in your custom subclass. This method would be called for each and evrery event of the application, including the user interaction events.

Comment: A problem was occur with this , the appdelegate wasn't call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method when i do this stuff

Comment: Are you sure you are subclassing UIApplication  properly. Also ensure that you replace UIApplication parameter and not the AppDelegate parameter in main.m.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method "Shoulder" in this Method make counter Variable If Count is Greater then 160 second then Do what you want.
and in touchBegin method Set this counter as Zero.